# Weird for loop behavior in Django template

Tags: django, dictionary, for-loop, django-templates

I am trying to write a `for` loop in my template as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

**views.py:**

```
def simple_view(self, request):
    adictionary = {'first': 'this is the first value', 
                   'second': 'this is the second value', 
                   'third': 'this is the third value'}
    return render_to_response("index.html", 
                            {'adictionary': adictionary}, 
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**index.html:**

```
{% for key, value in adictionary %}
    {{ key }} : {{ value }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

This is what i expect from the HTML output:

```
first : this is the first value
second : this is the second value
third : this is the third value
```

And this is what i get:

```
s : e 
t : h 
f : i
```

Does it make any sense to you? I am about to smash my keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `adictionary.items` to access `key, val`

```
{% for key, value in adictionary.items %}
    {{ key }} : {{ value }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As Google Chrome says: Awww, Snap! Thank you.

Comment: I will accept it but SO doesn't allow me yet. It needs 15 minutes after the question i think.